# vala Posix.lstat() error

Tags: posix, fuse, vala

I've got this piece of code:

```
using Posix;

int fuseguifs_getattr(string path, Posix.Stat *stbuf)
{
    int res;
    res = Posix.lstat(path, stbuf);
    if (res == -1)
        return -Posix.errno;

    return 0;
}

static int main(string [] args)
{
    Posix.Stat *a;
    fuseguifs_getattr("/home/leon", a);
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm trying to compile it I get this error:

```
test.vala:6.26-6.30: error: Argument 2: Cannot convert from
`Posix.Stat' to `Posix.Stat*'
    res = Posix.lstat(path, stbuf);
                            ^^^^^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

I've tried changing this:
        fuseguifs_getattr("/home/leon", a);
to
        fuseguifs_getattr("/home/leon", *a);

But then I get an error: "Cannot pass value to reference or output
parameter"

I've tried adding "out":
        res = Posix.lstat(path, out *stbuf);

That gives this error:
error: ref and out method arguments can only be used with fields,
parameters, local variables, and array element access

I can't change the fuseguifs_getattr method parameters because that's
part of how the fuse bindings expect it.

I'm really stuck. Does anyone how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to solve it:

```
int fuseguifs_getattr(string path, Posix.Stat *stbuf)
{
    int res;
    Posix.Stat a;
    res = Posix.lstat(path, stbuf);

    if (res == -1) {
        return -Posix.errno;
    }
    *stbuf = a;

    return 0;
}
```

Would that be the right way to go?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
int fuseguifs_getattr(string path, out Posix.Stat stbuf) {
   int res;
   res = Posix.lstat(path, out stbuf);
   if (res == -1)
      return -Posix.errno;
   return 0;
 }

static int main(string [] args)
{
    Posix.Stat a;
    fuseguifs_getattr("/home/leon", out a);
    return 0;
}
```

`Posix.Stat` is a struct that lstat is going to fill. Rather than pass a pointer to that structure, Vala expects you to indicate that it is going to be used as output by `lstat` using the `out` keyword which, like the `ref` keyword, must be specified on both declaration and use. So, any function definitions which are `out`, you must specify `out` again when you call the function.

Comment: I can't change the function definition by removing the pointer I believe. The method is defined by fuse: http://fuse.sourceforge.net/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#7a4c5d8eaf7179d819618c0cf3f73724

If I remove the pointer from stbuf in the function I get this error:
Cannot convert from `fuseguifs_getattr' to `Fuse.GetAttr' :(

Comment: The fuse.vapi has a really odd way of coding. It should probably be changed. The way you have done it below is fine given the VAPI.